# how do i make the image in each listitem have its own handler?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

[in the page,I learned how to use listbox](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/)

and here is a picture about the tutorial:
what i want to do is that:
i want to make the each item two pieces
**one is icon;another is text**

if I click the icon-car ,it popups a picture-car,but if I click the text on the right of icon-car,it can do other thing,*such as a new page full of text introduction*
I know the **SelectionChanged** handles the whole item
which means that even i click the icon or the text,it do the same thing
can u help me???Any advice will be great,sample code will be greater

[image]

Comment: Are these items dynamically loaded or are they all hard coded in with xaml?

Comment: hello it's dynamically loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where it says `<Image Source...`  put the cursor at the end of the word Image. Now hit spacebar and intelisense should pop open. Choose the keyword "tap" and hit tab. It should open an event handler selection after a moment. Choose "New Event" Then look in your back end code. At the base of your class there should be a new method. Type in what you want. Wash and repeat for the text blocks.